# CheckBox doesn't appear in CheckedTextView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-checkbox

When I set up my `CheckedTextView`, it has no `CheckBox`. Here is the xml code for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/checkedtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:checkMark="@android:attr/checkMark"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

replace

```
android:checkMark="@android:attr/checkMark"
```

by

```
android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
```

Comment: Try with `android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"` and if it still throws an Exception please attach your java code and the full stack trace

Answer (score 31):

Try : 
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"

Comment: This gives me the correct image, the accepted answer didn't

Comment: but, does the `CheckedTextView` behaviour doesn't able to have a click listener to be checked/unchecked? @Tobrun